# How to create an Insert trigger in mongodb atlas?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, database-trigger, mongodb-atlas

I am new to NoSQL/MongoDB and I need to write a trigger on insert    event on one of the collection in my database as follow: Database Name: GiftShop Collection Name: Gifts
Gifts Schema is as Follows:-

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const userModel = require('./userModel');
const imageModel = require('./imageModel');
const giftSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        availableQuantity: Number,
        price: Number,
        Seller: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'UserModel'},
        imageName: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'ImageModel'},
        deliveryInDays: Number,category: [{type: String, ref: 'CategoryModel'}]
        }, {collection: "gifts"});
module.exports = giftSchema;
```

I have another collection named as a notification. I want to create a trigger as such, as soon as the new gift gets inserted in gift collection the notification collection must get populated with the information having:
gift id,
seller id,
an array of buyer id.

the schema for notification is as follows:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const notificationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        seller: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'UserModel'},
        buyer: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'UserModel'}],
        newGift: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'GiftModel'}
        }, {collection: "notifications"});
module.exports = notificationSchema;
```

following is the function I wrote in MongoDB atlas but it has many issues with it:

```
exports = function (changeEvent) {
        const {fullDocument} = changeEvent;
        const {buyer, seller, newGift} = fullDocument;
        const collection = context.services.get("Cluster0").db("test").collection("notification");
return collection.insertOne({buyer, seller, newGift})};
```

the setup I did on MongoDB atlas to create my trigger:
[image]

[image]

I am inserting a new gift via MongoDB compass which is connected to my MongoDB atlas but my notification collection is not getting populated with the data mentioned in the schema of notification. Where am I going wrong? and what is the correct way to write the trigger according to my requirement? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are some pointers for debugging stitch functions [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/functions/call-a-function/), you should be able to follow those to determine if the issue is with your function or the trigger.

Comment: Hi, Oleg thank you for your help. But it is not working for me. I appreciate your help.